# fullpage.js incompatibility issue with mobile.js and camera.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

while I was trying to setup an image gallery I encountered an issue when calling *camera.js* [(here)](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/) and *mobile.js* [(here)](http://jquerymobile.com/) along with *fullpage.js* [(by Alvaro Trigo)]. The problem is that whenever I click on any of the hyperlinks in the top navbar, they just won't work. There's one that does though, but it redirects to another page instead of a section. It works perfectly fine without the gallery's scripts, and when imported, it all works except of the above. Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks in advanced.

Just in case, here's my navbar code:

```
 <ul id="menu">
        <li data-menuanchor="inicio" class="active normalmenu"><a href="#inicio">Inicio</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="descripcion" class="normalmenu submenuact"><a href="#quees">Qué es Rien Pipe</a>
            <div id="submenuact2">
                <ul id="submenu">   
                    <li data-menuanchor="descripcion" class="noborder"><a href="#descripcion">Descripción de Rien Pipe</a></li>
                    <li data-menuanchor="descripcion" class="noborder"><a href="#descripcion/1">La diferencia</a></li>
                    <li data-menuanchor="descripcion" class="noborder"><a href="#descripcion/2">Mecanismo</a></li>  
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </li>
        <li data-menuanchor="quienessomos" class="normalmenu"><a href="#quienessomos">Quiénes somos</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="preguntasfrecuentes" class="normalmenu"><a href="#preguntasfrecuentes">Preguntas frecuentes</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="testimonios" class="normalmenu"><a href="#testimonios">Testimonios</a></li>    
        <li data-menuanchor="contacto" class="normalmenu"><a href="#contacto">Contacto</a></li> 
        <li class="normalmenu"><a href="http://rienpipe.cloudapp.net/es/home/11-rien-pipe-primera-etapa.html">Hacer un pedido</a></li>  
    </ul>
```

and the gallery section:

```
         <div class="camera_pos">
            <div class="camera_wrap camera_azure_skin" id="camera_wrap_1">
                <div data-src="imgs/banner1.png">
                </div>
                <div data-src="imgs/banner2.png">
                </div>
                <div data-src="imgs/banner3.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are not initializing your other plugins inside the `afterRender` callback as detailed [in fullpage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterrender):

> **afterRender()**
>
> This callback is fired just after the structure of the page is generated. **This is the callback you want to use to initialize other plugins** or fire any code which requires the document to be ready (as this plugin modifies the DOM to create the resulting structure).

```
 $.fn.fullpage({
        afterRender: function(){
            //your plugins initialization here
            alert("The resulting DOM stucture is ready");
        }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I still struggle to get the point. I'm not sure how to call ('.camera_wrap').camera();, as when putting it under function, fullpage.js won't work anymore. Thanks again

Comment: You should place it inside `afterRender`. Maybe you are not calling correctly... I dont know the camera plugin so I can not help you with that aspect.